What are the remedies for weak mars?
Which mantras and stotras can cure weak mars in life? Also what are some quirks that one can follow to strengthen mars?

Without presenting horoscope, passing judgement about a planet is no good!

@Marmayogi you are correct . But as I am passing through this rough time I think it is due to weak mars . That’s why to be safe I wanted to find some way.

Then why don't you attach your horoscope (Rasi and Navamsa charts) along with detail of Balance of dasha? I suggest you to use Jaganath Hora software, take a screenshot, use Microsoft paint for cut & copy and then paste it on this post. Please know that there may be thousand astrological reasons for your rough patch, so don't jump the gun and blame Mars. Better arrive at conclusion after proper analysis with the help of your horoscope. If not possible, then at least provide your birth info (DoB, ToB, PoB) on the post and ask for help. Good Luck!

Good advice actually @Marmayogi. Thank you for it.

The following page provides various remedies for all 9 Grahas mars included - https://www.astrojyoti.com/mantras2.htm @Sillyasker

@Rickross thank you very much.

It depends on whether mars is a functional benefic or a functional malefic in your chart..if its malefic then one should not strengthen it as it will give negative result..
